# cannot import name 'nosetester' error while importing pandas

Tags: pandas

Im getting below error while importing pandas

cannot import name 'nosetester'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 56, in 
    from pandas.util.nosetester import NoseTester
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/util/nosetester.py", line 13, in 
    from numpy.testing import nosetester
ImportError: cannot import name 'nosetester'

Pandas version ->0.18.1
Numpy version ->1.18.0

Any help to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use python 3.6 version like 3.6.5 is a stable version.

Another approach is if you want to continue in python 3.5 version itself then python 3.5.2 it worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks nages!!. it seems numpy version and pandas version mismatch as well. so i have installed numpy 1.11.1 version  and pandas 0.19.2 version that worked for me

Comment: Thanks Jagan!! Yes, we need to figure it out the matching version between numpy and pandas at times.